# cordova platform add android JAVA_HOME error in Ubuntu

Tags: android, cordova

I'm trying to start android development with Cordova on Ubuntu. 
I can't add android platform for my project:

```
$ sudo cordova platform add android
Checking Android requirements...
[Error: ERROR : Make sure JAVA_HOME is set, as well as paths to your JDK and JRE for java.]
```

Environment checks:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)

$ ant -version
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on May 18 2012

echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/programs/adt-bundle/sdk/platform-tools:/programs/adt-bundle/sdk/tools

$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_45
```

Eclipse ADT-Boundle is in `/programs/adt-boundle` folder

Please, tell me, why am I still getting this error?

```
[Error: ERROR : Make sure JAVA_HOME is set, as well as paths to your JDK and JRE for java.]
```

Comment: has anyone found a fix to this?

Answer (score 2):

This got rid of the JAVA_HOME error for me:

`~/.bashrc` file:

`export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386`

I also had to add:

```
export PATH=~/path/where/I/put/bundle/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20131030/sdk/tools
export PATH=~/path/where/I/put/bundle/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20131030/sdk/platform-tools
```

to get past another error

Answer (score 0):

The error is simlar in Mac

I'm same bug

Checking Android requirements...
[Error: ERROR : Make sure JAVA_HOME is set, as well as paths to your JDK and JRE for java.]

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5422

Answer (score -1):

After few days I tried `cordova platform add android` again and it worked good. Wery strange. I changed nothing.

Comment: shucks. I'm getting the same error but don't want to wait for voodoo magic